# Angular6 create and pass a template from a parent component to a child

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm pretty new to angular, and am trying to create a custom table component to reuse throughout my application. 
And I have a simple example working by passing an array of data, and then an array of `Column` configurations.

My `Column` config looks like

```
export interface Column {
  field: string;  
  displayValue?: string;
  cellTemplate?;
}
```

and then in my `TableComponent` I build the table based off of the data and array of Columns passed in.

But now I want to try and make it a little more advanced, and be able to pass in the cellTemplate, something like

```
{
field: 'firstName',
displayValue: 'First Name',
cellTemplate: '<h1>My Name is {{cell}}</h1>
}
```

And then even a step further and be able to pass an onlclick event from the parent with it...

```
{
field: 'firstName',
displayValue: 'First Name',
cellTemplate: '<button (click)="parentClick(cell)">Click Me to find out my name</button>'
}
...
parentClick(cell){
alert('My Name is ' + cell);
}
...
```

But I'm kind of stuck. I've found I can pass a static template like `<h1>Hello World</h1>` and then use [innerHtml]="cellTemplate" but that's all I can figure out so far

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change template content using an expression or value, you can pass any value from parent component to child component by using @Input. But if you want to pass static template you can use content projection. Pleaes follow this link how to use content projection. https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/infragistics/posts/simplifying-content-projection-in-angular